# Automate the Boring Stuff Chapter 7: Regular Expressions - phone number and email extractor only extracting phone numbers

Tags: python

I am following the book and am pretty sure I copied the code verbatim. When I copy the Contact Us page on the publisher website (nostarch.com/ContactUs) and run it through the program, it outputs all the phone numbers but no email addresses.

I made sure the code was copied correctly. I thought it may be an issue with the print function so I tried pasting the result into a text file and the email addresses were still nowhere to be found.

```
import pyperclip, re

# email regex
emailRegex = re.compile(r'''(
    [a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+  # username
    @                  # at symbol
    [a-zA-Z0-9.-]+     # domain name
    (\.[a-zA-Z]{2-4})  #dot-something
    )''', re.VERBOSE)

# find matches in clipboard text
text = str(pyperclip.paste())
matches = []
for groups in phoneRegex.findall(text):
    phoneNum = '-'.join([groups[1], groups[3], groups[5]])
    if groups[8] != '':
        phoneNum += ' x' + groups[8]
    matches.append(phoneNum)
for groups in emailRegex.findall(text):
    matches.append(groups[0])

# copy results to the clipboard
if len(matches) > 0:
    pyperclip.copy('\n'.join(matches))
    print ('Copied to clipboard:')
    print ('\n'.join(matches))
else:
    print('No phone numbers or email addresses found.')
```

I expect to get the result:

```
Copied to clipboard:
800-420-7240
415-863-9900
415-863-9950
info@nostarch.com
media@nostarch.com
academic@nostarch.com
help@nostarch.com
```

but only got this:

```
Copied to clipboard:
800-420-7240
415-863-9900
415-863-9950
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`I made sure the code was copied correctly` - nope. You should replace `{2-4}` with `{2,4}` to look for 2 to 4 characters according to both RegEx syntax and chapter 7 text.

You may consider to use https://regex101.com/ to try your regular expressions online and see regex full explanation.

Comment: Upvoted for online checking suggestion.  Use those when you can.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing - went to the site and copied all text without looking at the content.  Then got the same output you did.  However, the reason was not because of broken code, but because I had disabled javascript on my browser.  Apparently, they hide their emails if they detect you don't have javascript enabled (i.e. if you are a bot).